# How can I inquire about some one else's border crossing history in Canada?

Tags: criminal-law, canada, borders

Googling about accessing information about traveling and border crossing history in Canada, I could only find information about how can one, access the information about SELF history of border crossings. 
What I want is to know IF a criminal individual is or is not in Canada.
His country of origin in which he has been proven guilty and has escaped from is Iran.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your relationship to this person?

Comment: @RonBeyer He is my ex.

Answer (score 4):

Without this person's consent, you can't.

https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/agency-agence/reports-rapports/pia-efvp/atip-aiprp/req-dem-info-eng.html

> Requests for personal information that is not the requester's must include signed, recent (less than one year old), written consent from the individual to whom the personal information belongs.

In theory it might be possible to get a court order to release this information to you.  I don't know under what circumstances that might be granted; I suspect it'd be very rare.  But you'd have to consult a lawyer about that.  If this person hasn't been convicted of anything in Canada, then presumably he still has his usual rights to privacy under Canadian law.

If he's wanted on suspicion of some crime, the police might be able to access this information to help find him; but you are not the police.

Comment: So you man even if I can track him down, I cannot ask Canadian officials to extradite him to Iran? Even though he has committed serious civil crimes including threat to kill?

Comment: @Gholi: You didn't ask about extradition and my answer has nothing to do with it - that's a completely separate question.  You can, in principle, ask the Canadian police whatever you want, and they will decide if it is warranted under Canadian law and applicable treaties.  As far as I can tell, there's no extradition treaty between Canada and Iran, which would make the chances of extradition unlikely (though not necessarily impossible).

Comment: @Gholi: But please note that this answer is mostly theoretical.  If this is an actual person with whom you have an issue, especially if you feel that you or others may be in danger, then this website is not a good place to get practical or legal advice on what to do - contact the police and/or a lawyer in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I called the police and they said they needed an address of him to do ANYTHING. I have not contacted any lawyer though, due to the expenses which are a lot I guess in Canada. So I have no choice but to ask my questions here and try to find the right course of action by seeking help here. Unless you tell me there is a way I can have a conquest lawyer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gholi: you speak of this person as a "criminal individual" and that "he has committed serious [...] crimes". These phrases would be accurate of someone who has been *convicted* of a serious offence, in which case he is probably inadmissible to Canada, if that conviction is known. If he has issued threats against you, you may be able to get  court order keeping him away from you, but I don't know if that would prevent him from entering Canada. You should probably seek out community services who can recommend legal services.